# empty memory cache automatically

Tags: linux, unix

any of you have an idea how you can set the cache memory so that when it reaches a certain limit is emptied automatically (example: I have the RAM to 1 GB, I wish the memory cahe empties automatically after it reaches 100 kb) thanks in advance

Comment: *What* "chaches" are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Linux uses all available free memory as page cache.

When applications require memory but there is no free memory, cache data is evicted from memory and that memory is made available to applications.

In other words, you do not need to do anything.

Comment: thanks, i'm using unix and if i call the unzip function from comand line the function craches("here the unzip function is for a lot of data ), have you any idea!?

Comment: @Bassem It can crash for many reasons. You want to post what you do, what output/errors you get, and what you expect.